# How can I programmatically set text to "Small Caps" in InDesign with ExtendScript?

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to do the equivalent of selecting some text and clicking on the *Small Caps* button. Here are a few attempts:

```
app.activeDocument.textFrames[0].texts.appliedCharacterStyle.capitalization = Capitalization.SMALL_CAPS;
```

Doesn't work: "Invalid request on a root style"

```
var myCharacterStyle = new CharacterStyle();
myCharacterStyle.capitalization = Capitalization.SMALL_CAPS;
app.activeDocument.textFrames[0].texts[0].applyCharacterStyle(myCharacterStyle);
```

Doesn't work: "Invalid value for parameter 'using' of method 'applyCharacterStyle'. Expected CharacterStyle, but received nothing."

How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start by creating a new character style if you want to change the default "[None]"

```
//First create a new character style
var newCharacterStyle = document.characterStyles.add(text.appliedCharacterStyle);
if(text.appliedCharacterStyle!=null){
    newCharacterStyle.basedOn = text.appliedCharacterStyle;
}   
text.appliedCharacterStyle = newCharacterStyle;

//then apply capitalization
newCharacterStyle.capitalization = Capitalization.SMALL_CAPS;
```

Comment: Works well, you just forgot one statement: `text.appliedCharacterStyle = newCharacterStyle;`. I tried applying this to all texts in a document: It works, but some text doesn't get transformed. To transform it, I just run the script a second time... Any clue why it works the second time and not the first? (There is no difference between the texts that work straight away and those that don't. For example, it will stop working in the middle of a sentence and start working again in the next paragraph.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a **buggy** way to set *Small Caps* on text:

```
app.activeDocument.textFrames[0].texts[0].appliedParagraphStyle.capitalization = Capitalization.SMALL_CAPS;
```

I say **buggy** because instead of setting *Small Caps* only on the wanted text, the whole paragraph is styled. This is the case because I use `appliedParagraphStyle` instead of `appliedCharacterStyle`. But when I use `appliedCharacterStyle`, I get "Invalid request on a root style." because the current `CharacterStyle` is that special one called "[None]". The "[None]" CharacterStyle doesn't allow writing to its appliedCharacterStyle property, nor does it allow duplication (with `duplicate()`).